# What are git branches used for?

Tags: git

I'm learning git and I don't understand why we need branches. Why not just develop in a "linear" fashion?

Comment: Because life isn't linear. Bug fixes on previous releases, new features that shouldn't be checked in yet, etc. all get in the way.

Answer (score 5):

Here's an excellent article on the matter: [A successful Git branching model](https://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/).

This picture (from the article) is pinned on my wall above the monitor :-)

[image: Branching model]
<sub>(source: [nvie.com](http://nvie.com/img/2009/12/Screen-shot-2009-12-24-at-11.32.03.png))</sub>

Comment: good idea to put the picture in the answer...wish I'd done that ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHorsdal: next time you'll do better :-)

Answer (score 3):

> Why not just develop in a "linear" fashion?

Because often time you could have members of your team work on two distinct copies of a project. Think for example that while you are fixing bugs on the production branch, customers are already waiting for the new features in the next version, so other team members work during this time on the development branch.

When the bugs are fixed, you release but of course the next version is not ready yet. If you developed in a linear manner, you would ship some incomplete feature but with fixed previous bugs. This is of course unacceptable. So you ship a service pack fixing the bugs to your customers, merge the bug fixes into the development branch and continue implementing the next version until it is ready to ship.

Answer (score 0):

Without branches, powerful workflows would not be possible - such as this one:

https://plus.google.com/109096274754593704906/posts/R4qkeyRadLR

Nothing is stopping you from using only the master branch if there's only you and perhaps a handful of others working on a project concurrently.